# Junk values while reversing a string?

Tags: c

My program is to reverse, even though the reverse is being generated but the problem is there is an unwanted junk values too.

I am not able to understand where the problem is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{   
    char ar[100],b[100];
    int i,j;
    scanf("%s",ar);
    j=strlen(ar); 
    printf("%d",j);
    j-=1;
    for(i=0;j>=0;i++)    
    {
       b[i]=ar[j];
       j--;
    }
    printf("\n %s",b);
}
```

This is the output:
[image]

Comment: you have to null-terminate your output string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
b[i] = 0;
```

at the end to terminate the string.

Answer (score 1):

The function `printf()` depends on the NUL-terminating character as a marker to stop printing, so you should terminate your array with the character '\0'. Also it would be better to make a function to reverse a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void m_strrev(char *str, char *output);

int main(void)
{
    char ar[100], b[100];
    //int i, j;
    scanf("%s", ar);
    /*j = strlen(ar) - 1;
    for (i = 0; j >= 0; i++)
    {
        b[i] = ar[j];
        j--;
    }
    b[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", b);*/
    m_strrev(ar, b);
    printf("%s\n", b);
}


void m_strrev(char *str, char *output)
{
    char *e = str;
    while (*e) {
        e++;
    }
    e--;
    while (e >= str) {
        *output++ = *e--;
    }
    *output = '\0';
}
```